# Flash content on Android API 19+

Tags: android, flash

I tried to do a small client for one mmorpg browser game for android. It shoud have contained only simple WebView with a SWF file loaded and then some buttons simulating keyboard keys press.

After reading few topics here and going through some tutorials, the major thing was clear. No flash on android API 19+ (last support by API 18)

BUT!
I have a phone with API 19, and I am still able to run flash content from browser.
Installation of plugin was required, I used UC Browser, which requested an installation of Adobe Flash 11.1 apk, downloaded it, and then .. vialaaa, flash content is available in that browser.

But I haven't found any tutorial for this, so my question is quite general.
How to get Flash content (especially SWF from WebView) available on Android API 19+? Can you please provide some tutorials, guides, links, or whatever? Because as I said .. found nothing relevant, but still, it is possible....

Thank you.